# Is it possible to find a Charizard in ORAS?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Can you find Charizard in *Pokemon Omega Ruby*? I got a Charizardite X and I have tried looking around the whole map and a I cannot find a Charizard.

If not, how do I get one?

Answer (score 3):

From the [wiki](https://au.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire/Charizard):

> ### Habitat
>
> This Pokemon cannot be found in Hoenn. Trade or transfer from another Pokemon game.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to find charizard, charmelean or charmander in Pokémon omega ruby and alpha sapphire. In order to get it you can trade from a different Pokémon game namely SilverSoul, GoldHeart, FireRed or LeafGreen. The last two are very old and are for the most part impossible to buy.

Where I found the information: https://www.supercheats.com/nintendods/questions/pokemonsoulsilver/174063/which-ds-pokemon-game-has-char.htm

Comment: One of the Kanto starters is given to the player in Pokemon X and Y which are 3DS games, so it is possible (and easier) to transfer them up from those games using PokeBank. Alternatively, some may be available for trade online directly in ORAS, from other people that have transferred them up. Needless to say, transferring up from GBA or DS games like you list is a lot more time consuming. :)